# Repeat task in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, getselection

Currently Im trying to write a simple firefox extension. I want to repeat my javascript code in every tab and if the user marks text the programm gives out an alert with the marked word.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "",
  "homepage_url": "",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/beasts-48.png"
  },

   "background": {
        "scripts": ["getMarkedText.js"]
    },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

And this is my getMarkedText.js that I want to give out the marked text:

```
function getMarkedText()
{
    if(window.getSelection)
    {
        alert(window.getSelection());
    }
    else if(document.getSelection)
    {
        alert(document.getSelection());
    }
    else if(document.selection)
    {
        alert(document.selection.createRange().text);
    }
}
```

If I run my getMarkedText.js over a button to test it it works perfectly but I cant figure out how to let it run automaticly in my firefox extension.

Thanks in advance for every answer

Sincerly

Hansi